What is the meaning of "chabeen" in Conde's "The Gospel According to the New World"?
In Maryse Conde's final novel, The Gospel According to the New World, an artist named Roro Manigas  is described as having painted  a series entitled Virgin and Child:

where one canvas represented a Black woman, one an Indian woman, one a
Dougla, a Chabeen, a Capresse, a Mulatto woman, and finally an
Octoroon

 Part One, Chapter 9 
These seem to be terms for various races and inter-racial mixings: a mulatto is a person with one white and one black parent, and an octoroon is a person who is one-eighth black by descent. Of the more unusual words, a "dougla" is a person of mixed African and Indian descent, and I have found that a "capresse" (used for example by the sculptor Charles Cordier) refers to a woman of predominantly African and some European ancestry (some say, more precisely, the daughter of a mulatto and a black).
This leaves "Chabeen", which I have not turned up any information on. Conde uses the term quite often during the novel, referring for example to a "high yellow Chabeen perched on her high heels". What does the word signify?

The French dictionary le Robert defines chabin/chabine as

(Antilles, Haïti) Métis aux traits de type africain, aux cheveux crépus blonds ou roux et à la peau claire,

which Google translates as

Mixed race with African features, frizzy blond or red hair and light skin.

This word has two versions, depending on gender. For men, it's chabin and for women, it's chabine. The female version chabine is pronounced shabeen, which is probably why the translator chose the spelling chabeen and not chabine.
One additional note: for hair, crépu is translated as kinky and not frizzy by wiktionary (not that it really matters in this context).
And finally in the comments, @Spagirl corrected me: high yellow actually refers to skin color and not hair color.

Yellow in ‘high yellow’ referred to skin colour so doesn’t distinguish between blonde or red/haired women.

I do find it slightly odd that the translator chose to change the spelling, or given that he did, he didn't opt for "shabeen".

@ClaraDíazSanchez: Maybe the translator thought that chabeen was close enough to the French pronunciation.  I figured out that the word was chabine by guessing that chabeen had been respelled in translation, and googling it. (But I probably would have done the same thing for shabeen.)
